# What is the purpose of the emacs menu bar in console mode?

Tags: emacs, emacs23

Loading emacs into the terminal (console) window, at the top is a menu containing File, Edit, Options, etc. As far as my googles have told me, the way to access it is by F10, M-x menu-bar-open, etc. However, this opens a new buffer with the contents of the menu bar. This seems ridiculous to me. Why would the developer want to waste an entire line of available screen with a menu that doesn't do anything?

Unless there is a way to expand a menu item, like have "File" open downward and let me select options with my keyboard without opening a new buffer (which I can't figure out how to do), I don't see any purpose to having a menu bar at the top other than to remind me that File, Edit, etc. exists.

So is there a way to get a menu item to expand? Or is it just a reminder?

Comment: It is ridiculous. Disable it and stop worrying. `(menu-bar-mode -1)`

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your .emacs file: `(menu-bar-mode -1)`

All problems solved.

To be fair, when you press f10, it highlights 'file' when you are not in console mode.